# Having problems accessing localhost/phpmyadmin on google chrome. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, google-chrome, localhost

Google chrome won't let me access `phpMyAdmin`.
It gives me this error message:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have tried

- `localhost/phpmyadmin`
- `localhost:/phpmyadmin`
- `localhost://phpmyadmin`
- `localhost//phpmyadmin`
- `localhost:phpmyadmin`
  and
- `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

But it always gives me the same error code.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What kind of webserver you are using in local PC? Please note that localhost is the domain, not protocol, so you don't have to try localhost://. Just https:// or https://, try it.

Comment: How did you install PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: From the website. Then I dragged the files onto my desktop, and changed blowfish secret to a long random string of letters and numbers.

Comment: How do I check what kind of webserver?